# Why do values values in a dataframe change when converting from int to float and back?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am getting very strange behavior for a series of SKUs in my code when using "astype(float)" and "astype(int) and I am at a loss to explain why. This seems to only happen on my local machine (I couldn't duplicate it in an online Juypter Notebook).

Here is a list of products where this problem occurs and the DF I am creating with them:

```
products = {'SKU': [1111000120,1111000160,1111000182,1111000210,1111001300,2412601027,
            2412601449,5172100236,5172100370,5172100713,7130104717]}


dfprod = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(products)
```

when I convert this df to fload and then back to int on my local machine I get the following: [Conversion error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjpG8.png)

I found this question that treats a similar problem but is about C++ so I'm not too sure how applicable it is. 
[sign changes when going from int to float and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453449/sign-changes-when-going-from-int-to-float-and-back)

Comment: This is probably a case of integer overflow. The value probably exceed the maximum size of the integer type.

Comment: Makes sense. But why would it only happen on my local machine then?

Comment: Compare your machine's `maxsize` with that each value in that dataframe: `import sys; dfprod.SKU.apply(lambda x: sys.maxsize < float(x)).any()`? Maybe that `maxsize` is less than some of the values?

Comment: I just checked and unfortunately that's not the solution. The maxsize is: 9223372036854775807

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this behavior on my machine. Are you by any chance using an old pandas version? In any case, `dfprod.astype(float).astype(np.uint64)` runs just fine on my machine with the use of numpy integer types.