# Java Widening Conversion

Tags: java, precision

`int big = 1234567890;
 float approx = big;
 System.out.println(big - (int)approx);`

The system prints out -46. I thought that float only allows for 7 significant figures meaning the operation would be 1234567890-1234567=1,233,333,323. How is it possible for it to print -46?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sign changes when going from int to float and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453449/sign-changes-when-going-from-int-to-float-and-back)

Comment: Not a duplicate of both proposals. The OP does not understand why 1234567 is not the closest approximation of 1234567890. That has nothing to do with anything at all.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/, e.g. printing the value of `approx`, which would instantly have highlighted your misconception of what "7 significant figures" means. I mean, if the code prints `-46` when you expect `1233333323` from a simple subtraction operation, the very first thought should be that the two values of the subtraction are not what you think they are, and printing them would be the next step in **RESEARCHING** the issue by yourself.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1159/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a problem with the interpretation of the phrase "significant figure"?

Whether you have

```
1234567890 US-dollars
```

or

```
1234567936 US-dollars
```

is not *that significant* of a difference.

But if you instead had

```
   1234567 US-dollars
```

that would be a *very* significant difference.

```
1234567890
^       ^
|        \
|         less significant
|
very significant
```

Thus, an approximation of

```
1234567890
```

to 7 decimal significant figures is something between (approximately)

```
1234567390
```

and (approximately)

```
1234568390
```

In this case, it turns out to be roughly

```
1234567936
```